# Display SQL information on C# RadioButtons

Tags: c#, radio-button, sql-server-ce, sqlcedatareader

My C# program is connected to my SQL CE Database. I use a SQLCEDATAREADER to fill some of the textboxes in my program. I have a "Gender" column in my database and a radiobutton with Male and Female. If a certain entry in my database has "M" in the gender column, how can I make the Male radio button appear pressed?

I tried

```
if(dr["Gender"].ToString = "M")
{
    rbMale = true
}
```

That obviously didnt work.

Comment: What do you mean by _didn't work_? You get any exception or error message? `=` is an assingment operator, if you wanna compare your strings, you need to use `==` instead. Since `ToString` is a method, you need to use it as `ToString()`. And `rbMale = true` needs to `;` at the end of the line.

Comment: Right syntax should be `if(dr["Gender"].ToString() == "M") { rbMale = true; }` but we _still_ need more information about your problem.

Comment: Well it says 
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton"

Comment: Looks like `rbMale` is `RadioButton`, it is too normal to get this error. Look it's `Checked` property. You can get and set this property if your condition returns `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(dr["Gender"].ToString() = "M")
    rbMale.Checked = true
else
    rbFemale.Checked = true
```

Comment: What if `dr["Gender"]` is null ? ;)

Comment: if (!string.isNullOrEmpty(dr["Gender"].ToString()))  :o

Comment: `if (Convert.ToString(dr["Gender"]) == "M")`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps collapse to one line -

```
rbMale.Checked = (Convert.ToString(dr["Gender"])=="M");
```

Comment: This answer is definitly better. : one line boolean affectation, cannot throw a NullReferenceException (`dr["Gender"]` null). The external `()` are not necessary though, it makes the code less readable. Less is more ;) One point though, if the asker don't want to change the state of the box if `false` : this code do it.

Answer (score 0):

If `rbMale` is the name of your radio button control, you can mark it checked by setting its `Checked` property to `true`.

`rbMale.Checked = true;`